# PC accessing from remote site

Tags: networking

I have Head Office and remote site, both location have different IP Addresses (Head Office 10.10.1.x mask 255.255.255.0, Remote IP 10.20.3.X mask 255.255.255.0), my scenario is that I have a PC IP Address 10.10.1.x where core application is executing. If we change the IP application will not work. I like to configure the backup server at remote site so in case of Head Office data centre failure users able to do work through remote site.
Now I configure the PC IP Address 10.10.1.x mask 255.255.255.0 at remote site where IP scheme is 10.20.3.x and subnet mask 255.255.255.0. Kindly help me how I can access PC at Remote site when Head Office PC fails.

Regards
Zaman

Comment: Can you tell your enviorenment in detail? Do you have naming services? DHCP services? 10.10.1.x IP adress is hard-coded in the application? Is the application is running over a share by multiple users? What is **"If we change the IP application will not work"**?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of to do this would be to set up a VPN client on the system at the remote site, and a VPN server on the network at your home office.  Then if you have to switch to the backup server at the remote site, start the VPN client, and make sure the VPN server is configured to let you use the address you want.  This would effectively extend the home office network to the remote site.

Whether your application will work this way is something you'd need to test and determine for yourself, as you don't mention why your application needs to use this address - and if the application is actually testing the address (for software license reasons or something), it could possibly get confused if it tries to do this on a system with multiple active network interfaces.  Whether this will work also depends on exactly what is down in the home office data center - this strategy assumes that the home office's basic network infrastructure is still up and working.  And also, of course, check with your company's IT organization to make sure that you'd be allowed to do this in the first place.